# jumbotron setting full width of browser

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a jumbotron bootstrap element to take the full width of the page, I tried with both col-xs-12 and with w-100 class but that is doesn't change anything.

can someone guide me how to change width and height of jumbotron element

**CSS**

```
<style>
.form-group {margin-top:1px}
 .jumbotron { color: #ec971f;width: 100%; margin-buttom:1px;max-resolution: res;rginbuttom:0px;}
.jumbotron p {color:blue;}
 .jumbotron { .navbar-brand{font-weight: bold;font-family: Verdana;font-size:12px }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" style= "margin-top:52px;"  >
      <div class="jumbotron well col-xs-12 w-100">
        <center> <h4 style="font-weight:bold">Sales</h4> </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no `w-100` class in Bootstrap 3. You should be using a `container-fluid`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to overwrite the the Css in bootstrap and if you use flex box on container and flex basis on the jumbotron. it will will cover the width